# ASP .NET MVC Best practice to authenticate and keep user-auth during his work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am just investigating the issue and get many different suggestions, can someone be helpful in detailing the subject include

- existing methods
- restrictions
- pros and cons
- protection against attacks

I look for a short review to get direction.

**EDIT:**

The audience are user from world-wide that need to register.

Comment: `keep user-auth during his work` There are a lot of way to authenticate a user; ASP.NET Identity is the latest one.  What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Otherwise, your question is too broad.

Comment: @shdr you have of had coworkers up vote this question, it makes almost no sense, this is hardly english...will vote to close as soon as you bounty expires

Comment: Would probably be best if you further defined the parameters around your application. For example, is it available internally only/externally/both? Is there an onsite implementation of active directory? Azure active directory? Are you hosting it onsite? Azure?external provider?

Comment: jwt token controlled by Identityserver ?

Comment: @Travis Acton you right i had to detail it battter: the application is for user from world wide that need to register to get service. editting my question.

Comment: @BrianOgden I'm sorry, assuming you right (which is not) isn't it legal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing in an answer here from some of the systems I have had professional experience with:

Note: I can further define positive/negatives if you answer the question I put in the comments about the parameters around your application.

**ASP.NET Identity**

Basic MS user system that ships with MVC framework that uses username and password. A plus side to this is that the concept has been around for a long time and there are tons of tutorials showing you how to extend it to use things such as email/password or collect certain data from your users like their mother's dogs middle name or whatever. You also would want to look here if you have an environment where users could possibly share computers. Think factory or hospital setting kinda deal. A negative to this is that you are basically forced to maintain the entire user setup, application roles, user management all contained within your application (or cluster of applications). Think Forms auth when it comes to this. You may want to look at this if your application is external and exposing AD services makes your security team uncomfortable.

**Windows Auth.**

You are basically authenticating against the Windows user account and although not necessary, for the most part you would treat something such as Active directory for your role provider. The plus side to this is that your application is really no longer responsible for user management and all the support that comes along with it (weeeeee!) but instead you are more  authorizing roles to work within your application. This makes it a breeze BUT a huge downfall is if you have users that may possibly share computers then this is a huge security nightmare. You would want to target users who have their own specific computer where they come to work and sit with this one. This becomes a nightmare if your application is externally hosted as it is easy to make your AD vulnerable as some of its services will need to be accessed externally.

**Forms/Windows hybrid model**

In this you basically configure your site to run on forms auth BUT your forms auth system is set to auth users in AD as a background process. So this is more for when you have a mix of users where some are sharing computers and some have dedicated computers. You are basically setting up your own forms auth website that takes in a redirect url along with the user's user AD name and password. The forms auth website then checks if the users credentials are valid in Active Directory, sets fun things like a session cookie and redirects the user back to your MVC site(s) with an authenticated user. On your MVC site(s) you have AD connectors as well (or you could have a N tier design to look it up) to tell you what AD groups the user belongs to and handle appropriately. So plus to systems like this is that you take the user management aspect away from your single site and place that responsibility back into AD but at the same time you have the flexibility to launch application that are basically windows auth into environments that have mixed user (people with dedicated comps and those who share.) Downside to this is that initial first time setup is a massive pain because you are essentially building out multiple systems. Also, security is also a concern with this as anytime you have a shared computer environment things are more susceptible to abuse. You have to some up with a good session timeout policy and live and die by that. Also you can place your forms with site in the DMZ and separate external hosted applications from directly interacting with AD. A minus though is you will need to handle things like AD lockouts, password reset, brute force attempts and such.

**External provider such as facebook, twitter, google with something like OAuth**.

I have never personally gone down this path on a production application so I cannot give you the real world positive or negatives but it needs to be mentioned and maybe someone else can give us some insight there.

Apologies on the massive textblocks in this answer, will make the format a bit "prettier" when I can get to a desktop.

Comment: i see in government, banks... sites. they use a token and i feel like i'm redirecting with a token, are they use kind of what you said **Forms/Windows hybrid model**, do you know?

Comment: @shdr It can be a hybrid model. Token more or less replaces things like session state. You will still need to authenticate your user and authorize roles. Token is becoming more popular for technologies that run on stateless mediums. Think ios or android phone apps. It is becoming more popular in MVC because 1 page applications are kind of the "In" thing right now. When you have a browser based technology such as MVC that loads its application as one page and relies heavily on AJAX to call back to the controller or an API service layer then you will have issues with session state timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ASP.NET MVC Framework you can authenticate users with ASP.NET Identity or with an external provider(Google, Facebook, Microsoft, etc).

In Visual Studio, if you create a new ASP.NET MVC project and choose to authenticate using individual accounts, it will setup the Identity system for you. 
And To keep users authenticated, I usually add the [Authorize] attribute above the controller class that I want to restrict access to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it might helpful or not -

But we use signalR to see whether the User is connected and authenticated to the server or not all the time while he is doing his work.

Comment: im curious about this setup. Are you just checking against the hub that the user is authorized? ive got a pretty decent grasp of signalR but never heard of anyone using it as such. Can you explain your architecture?

Comment: I join to @TravisActon question

Comment: Our architecture is single page asp.net MVC application with Knockout.js with most of them are partial views. As soon as the user is authenticated by any of the Identity providers (Asp.Net Identity or windows Auth or google or anything ) and we save their user details in the session, we make the light weight call to the server a the regular interval to make sure the user's that User host is still active on the server or not.